# Wix - Installing an app off the c:\ root instead of program files and creating shortcuts

Tags: wix

this is the markup i used to create the directory structure and create sub directories. it does work just fine. it creates the software directory of the c:\ root and creates the sub directories under that. But then i add a new component group called "shortcuts". I want to create a short cut on the start menu and a desktop icon.i am not sure of what to call the id where the ?????? are in the start menu directory. i also get the following error when i build the project.

Error   1   The Component/@Directory attribute was not found; it is required.
it occurs twice. one at this line Component Id="cmpStartMenuShortcut" and one at this line  Component Id="cmpDesktopShortcut"

```
 <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
        <Directory Id="SoftwareDirectory" Name="UnionAdministrator">
          <Directory Id="RuntimeFolder" Name="Runtime" />
          <Directory Id="ReportsFolder" Name="Reports" />
          <Directory Id="TasksFolder" Name="Tasks" />
          <Directory Id="DebugLogsFolder" Name="DebugLogs" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id ="FontsFolder" />
      <Directory Id ="???????????r">
        <Directory Id="AppStartMenuFolder" Name="Runtime" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" />
    </Directory>

    <SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Value="[WindowsVolume]" />
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents">
      <Component Id="cmpCreateRuntimeFolder"
                 Guid="{27D409D8-8D86-4CB0-8165-E30A6E3998EC}"
                 Directory="RuntimeFolder">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpCreateReportsFolder"
                 Guid="{9621003B-0BDC-44D8-B981-C5B9CA76C733}"
                 Directory="ReportsFolder">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpCreateTasksFolder"
                 Guid="{785A0024-16B2-499D-9B67-6BCBB8094C55}"
                 Directory="TasksFolder">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpCreateDebugLogsFolder"
                 Guid="{9C91955B-967A-411D-ACD9-6C6AA15F84E8}"
                 Directory="DebugLogsFolder">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

 <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="Shortcuts">
      <Component Id="cmpStartMenuShortcut"
                         Guid="{2A561F4E-118A-4927-9C29-7FF441B77097}">
        <Shortcut Id="StartMenuShortcut"
                        Name="Union Adminstrator"
                        Description="Runs UnionAdminstrator"
                        Directory="AppStartMenuFolder"
                        Target="[RuntimeFolder]UnionAdministrator.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpDesktopShortcut"
                     Guid="{6A686136-06D9-469B-93BA-076D5F32D46B}">
        <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut"
                        Name="Union Adminstrator"
                        Description="Runs UnionAdminstrator"
                         Directory="DesktopFolder"
                        Target="[#FILE_UAEXE] " />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give directory for shortcuts.and assign it like you have done for other components.
Also since you cant give shortcut as keypath, you could keep registry in shortcut component as keypath.